# How to get value return from a function within a loop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to work out how to test the return value of a function call within a loop and breaks the loop if function returns a specific value.

The follow piece of batch script is my attempt, the function return expected value on the first 2 function calls. When the call is made within a loop, I cannot figure out how to test the return value. Please point me to a direction on how to test the function return value within the loop.

```
SET var1=2
SET var2=0
CALL :FUNC %var1 var2
ECHO var2 is: %var2%

REM ============================

SET var1=6
SET var2=0
CALL :FUNC %var1 var2
ECHO var2 is: %var2%

REM ============================

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET list=1 0 3 4
FOR %%n IN (%list%) DO (
    CALL :FUNC %%n rtn
    IF !rtn! == 0 (
        GOTO DONE
    )
)
ECHO rtn is: %rtn%

: DONE
PAUSE
GOTO :eof


REM %1 is an in parameter
REM %2 is an out parameter
: FUNC
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET var=%1
EndLocal & SET %2=%var% & GOTO :eof
```

Comment: there are no such things like `setlocal`, `goto :eof` or function call... in DOS. [Those are cmd features](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: When you write `CALL :FUNC %var1 var2` you actually mean `CALL :FUNC %var1% var2`, don't you?

Comment: @aschipfl, yes you are right. This is not the production batch script, I wrote this just to demonstrate the real issue I have in my production batch script, and have a typo in there as you've pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see any problems with your loop, but with your function.
You only need to change the last line to (the quotes are new):
`EndLocal & SET "%2=%var%" & GOTO :eof`

Without the quotes, you always appended a single space to your return value,
therefore the `IF !rtn! == 0 (` was always false

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand why it needs the quotes. Is there any reference I can read?

Comment: @simon `SET %2=%var% & GOTO :eof` Note the space between `%var%` and the ampersand `&`. That extra space is not delimiter but is considered as part of the assigment. Compare it with `SET %2=%var%& GOTO :eof` and see the difference. In general with the form `set "a=b"` the last quote marks the end of the  assignment and the `set` command ignores everything after the last quote. There is no official reference for this specific syntax of the the `set` command.

Comment: Thanks sst. So what if I do SET a="b" &... Does that space before the & stores into the variable a as well?

Comment: @simon `SET a="b" ` is very different to `SET "a=b" `. In the first case `a` contains `"b"<space>` (two quotes and a space, total of 4 characters), in the second case `a` only contains a single `b`. The second form is often referenced as **extended set syntax**

Comment: @simon They are two different things. With the form `set a="b" & ...` Not only the space will be stored in the variable but also the the quotes. try `set a="b" & echo [%a%]` to see the result.

Comment: Thank you jeb and sst. If I interpret you correct, that means the `SET` command take the entire string to the right of the `=` sign until it hits the end of line or a character that is known by `SET` as termination character; in this case it is the `&`.

Comment: @simon, the `&` is not specifically recognised by `set`, it is recognised earlier when parsing the command line...

Comment: In my last comment there is a flaw in the code example. This is the correct one: `set a="b" & call echo [%%a%%]` valid within a batch file. Or `set a="b" & echo [!a!]` if delayedExpansion is on